# While loop in a button onclickListener()

Tags: android

[image: this is the code where the SendMessageToServer is running but the Dot.setX is not.]I have a button `onClickListener()` inside which, there is a `while` loop which keeps on displaying the position, by setting the coordinates of the `imageview`. The problem is that the whole loop is running but the image moves only after the final loop is executed. please help. It's a tracking application using wifi.

Comment: Can you post those codes??

Comment: Put some code/error here so that we can give you proper answer.

Comment: A while loop on the main thread ? This blocks the UI from updating.

Comment: Seems like UI thread is busy executing while loop and once its done it make the change to imageview. Put the loop on a different thread and use a handle to update the UI.

Comment: what the ...?! Any way why is a while loop in the onClicklistenern? Maybe you want to redraw it or made an animation ? See the docu here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: yes i think the problem is with the ui updation.but is there a a way to have it in the main thread.??

Comment: I didn't see any `while` loop or button click listner in your code..

Comment: the snapshot is of the code running inside the button click listener inside which there is a while loop.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because all work which you do is in MainThread.

MainThread updating the UI but because you updating a coordinate in mainthread too, then MainThread don't have time to update UI and you see last operation only.

Try move updating coordinate to new thread and refresh a UI by 
view.post() method.

Comment: Thanks.Thats a bit clear.But i want to do it in the main thread.Is there a way?

Comment: No, but it is easy to change. Create an AsyncTask, put the loop in `doInBackground` and the update in `onProgressUpdate` and you can call the second method from the first with `publishProgress`.